# Метод app.run длится бесконечно

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, pyrogram, декоратор

Например есть скрипт:

```
import pyrogram

app = Client(***)

def hi():
  print("Привет")

app.run()
hi()
```

Метод `app.run()` вызывает бесконечный цикл.

Кто разбирается в нем, подскажите что пошло не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyrogram import Client, idle

app = Client(***)
app.start()
# тут выполнять нужные функции
idle()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def start():
    app.start()
    hi()
```

если понадобится чтобы после `app.start()` вызвалась `hi()` используйте `start()`.

Comment: после строчки app.run() в модуле происходит бесконечный цикл и ничего не воспринимается ПОСЛЕ нее!!!

Comment: вы неправильно выразили вопрос, нужно было спрашивать не о том как реализовать функцию, а что делать если модуль длится бесконечно и в названии также не "Выполнение функции после app.start()", а " Метод app.start длится бесконечно Pyrogram" или что то типа этого

Comment: вопрос решен на другом форуме, спасибо